# UPDATE IF DUPLICATE INSERT? w autoincrement PK on INSERT?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

Given two tables:

```
`Students`
id         int, primary, auto-increment
sid        int
fname      varchar
lname      varchar


`Registration`
id          int, primary, auto-increment
student_sid int
coursenum   int
```

Is there a way to populate a new column in `Students` with the coursenum of each of the classes they registered for?  So every time a second coursenum was added for a given sid, students.id would auto-increment, remaining the primary key, while a new row with the sid, fname, lname and new coursenum  would be added to the table.

It's kind of like a backwards version of INSERT...IF DUPLICATE UPDATE.  I want UPDATE...IF DUPLICATE INSERT.

Comment: This seems like a really odd thing to want to do. Might want to rethink your database design. I would expect you to have just one ID field (call it studentID) in the Students table, one record per student. The Registration table could have its own ID field, but it seems unnecessary. It should have a studentID field and a coursenum field. One entry per student per course, so if three students are taking four classes each, there will be three entries in the Students table and 12 entries in the Registration table.

Comment: Further, you might want to use a courseID instead of coursenum and have another relational table that has information about each course (name, number, professor, credits, etc.).

Comment: Agreed!  I don't have control over the database design, nor the application that needs these fields from these tables.  I'm just trying to find a way to populate the data with a query as opposed to by hand.

Comment: Are you able to use PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can do something like this (see notes below):

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT student_sid from Registration");
while (list($studentID) = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT fname, lname FROM Students WHERE sid = '{$studentID}'");
    list($fname, $lname) = mysql_fetch_row($result2);

    mysql_query("DELETE FROM Students WHERE sid = '{$studentID}'");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO Students (sid, fname, lname, coursenum) SELECT '{$studentID}', '{$fname}', '{$lname}', coursenum FROM Registration WHERE student_sid = '{$studentID}'");
}
```

A few notes here:

1. This code is not tested, but I think it should work without errors.
2. This will not preserve the original `id` column from the `Students` table. It will get the first and last name, then delete the student, and insert a new row for each entry in the `Registration` table. It will preserve the `sid`, `fname`, and `lname`, and will populate a new column `coursenum`.
3. This also assumes that you have already altered the `Students` table to include a `coursenum` column.
4. Depending on how many students and courses you're talking about here, this code may not be the fastest in the world, but I'm assuming that this isn't something that will be done regularly...more of a one-time migration kind of thing.

Hopefully this helps you.

Comment: I think this is a great solution. Thanks.